# Remove first space in directories name recursively

Tags: linux

I have reencoded a huge collection of music and now, I don't know why, all the directories name begin with a space.

I want to know how to remove this space in all the directories name without having to do it one directory by one directory

Thanks per advance for your answer

P.S. : Sorry if my english is not good, I am french.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have not tried anything, I have asked here before to search on internet. I do not want to remove all the spaces in the Path, I want to remove the first one. The space I want remove is at the beginning of each folder name.

Answer (score 0):

This works in *Debian*:

It will remove **ALL** the spaces in the **Path**. If the parent directories contain spaces they wil go away also.

```
find $PWD -type d -name ' *' | rename -v  's/ //g'
```

You must be in the parent directory of the directories that you need to change.